# Can I install SQL Server on an external Hard Disk?

Tags: sql-server, hard-drive, installation, ssd

I have a desktop PC (Windows 7) with 1 TB HDD which has SQL Server 2008 R2 installed. Now it is getting replaced by a laptop with 500G SSD drive. This would be first experience working with a SSD. But I have been told not to install SQL Server 2008 R2 on SSD drive. Can I buy an external hard disk and install SQL Server 2008 R2 on it? Will the database work transparently with the laptop in this way?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Aside from this question being OT in the first place, there is no reason at all to not install SQL Server on a SSD drive; but even if there *was* one, or if you just didn't want to install it on your system drive... installing it on an external disk makes *definitely* a lot less sense.

That said, you can do that and it will work (as long as you keep the external disk plugged in); but it's just an astonishingly bad setup.

Comment: Laptop has only 1 Hard Disk Drive bay. And I did not get permission to install SQL Server on it; the reason I was given: the Hard Disk is SSD and it is not recommended to install any database on SSD. What other option I have to get SQL Server other than an external disk?

Comment: "Not recommended" by whom? That statement doesn't make any sense without some context (and even with context...).

Comment: "Not recommended" by the IT support personnel in my company. These are the guys who setup PCs/laptops in my company and would report me if I installed something which they have not recommended which in case may result in my firing.

Comment: @srh sorry for your company, but this still doesn't make any sense. Please advise them to get a f**kin' clue. And change company as you can.